# What could cause a ping request to return inconsistently timed results

Tags: networking, wifi, ip, ping

Here is a sample run:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=8852.917 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=7918.074 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=6919.258 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=6554.894 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=5555.114 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=6811.810 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=5817.897 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=4820.810 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=3823.977 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=2905.626 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=1906.395 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=905.815 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=4559.416 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=3560.627 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=2563.604 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=42 ttl=64 time=1571.941 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=572.513 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=44 ttl=64 time=785.998 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=45 ttl=64 time=91.560 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=46 ttl=64 time=207.244 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=47 ttl=64 time=168.893 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=48 ttl=64 time=882.917 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=49 ttl=64 time=613.126 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=50 ttl=64 time=355.128 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=51 ttl=64 time=764.870 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=52 ttl=64 time=1171.386 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=53 ttl=64 time=171.749 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=54 ttl=64 time=222.467 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=55 ttl=64 time=256.847 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=56 ttl=64 time=480.801 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=58 ttl=64 time=1036.218 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=59 ttl=64 time=35.761 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=60 ttl=64 time=139.025 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=61 ttl=64 time=74.907 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=62 ttl=64 time=96.822 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=63 ttl=64 time=15.899 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=64 ttl=64 time=286.599 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=65 ttl=64 time=1818.499 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=66 ttl=64 time=819.665 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=67 ttl=64 time=1164.031 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=68 ttl=64 time=977.344 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=69 ttl=64 time=987.560 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=70 ttl=64 time=2449.542 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=71 ttl=64 time=1450.172 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=72 ttl=64 time=1582.838 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=73 ttl=64 time=1155.943 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=74 ttl=64 time=364.404 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 82
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=78 ttl=64 time=5450.020 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=79 ttl=64 time=4451.254 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=80 ttl=64 time=3537.117 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=81 ttl=64 time=2598.308 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=82 ttl=64 time=1599.324 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=83 ttl=64 time=706.184 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=84 ttl=64 time=651.453 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=85 ttl=64 time=37.370 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=86 ttl=64 time=385.340 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=88 ttl=64 time=266.425 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.9 ping statistics ---
89 packets transmitted, 57 packets received, 36.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.899/2033.889/8852.917/2287.084 ms
```

I've edited to include details regarding my network speed below.

[image: Speed Test #1]

[image: Speed Test #2]

Comment: what are you pinging ? if it's a local computer on wifi that could be explain easilly :D

Comment: @Kiwy it is. What are you thinking?

Comment: what is the speed test from the device your trying to reach ? the wifi connection might be disturb by something.

Comment: @Kiwy No, that is just the wireless I have. Perhaps I had too many connections running at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

A poor network connection. That's it.

Also these results aren't inconsistent, they make perfect sense.
Lets take a look at this section for example:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=6811.810 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=5817.897 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=4820.810 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=3823.977 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=2905.626 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=1906.395 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.9: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=905.815 ms
```

Notice how the times continuously decrease by almost 1000ms each line?
That happens because your machine sends ping #32, one second later sends #33, second later #34, etc. Then it gets all the responses at the same time. So #32 was sent 6.8 seconds ago, #33 was sent 5.8 seconds ago, etc.

Somewhere along the line something has a very poor link. And so the network traffic is getting buffered. As soon as the link is good, it flushes that buffer.

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Comment: Holy cow. Just logged on here before going to bed. Was not expecting that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Saw you were close so I thought I'd help you out and push you over the hump. It's a nice milestone.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded network, or overloaded server.

('tho it's possible to cause this with traffic shaping -- on purpose, or (usually) by accident.)

Comment: Overloaded network would generally result in more `request timed out` messages as the network buffer would be full, and so it wouldn't be able to accept any traffic. Since most of the packets are being responded to, it shows the buffer is fairly empty, just takes a long time to send the traffic.

Comment: Maybe only in one direction.  And there may be some deep buffers in there. As it's a private address, one might think it's fairly local, but that's not necessarily true. (my private address is over a VPN, but appears to everything else that I'm on the local lan)